Alternative to deprecated MachO getsegbyname function?
The MachO getsegbyname function (see here) has been marked 'deprecated' by Apple as of iOS 16.0 and MacOS 13.0 with the note 'No longer supported':
extern const struct segment_command *getsegbyname(
    const char *segname) __CCTOOLS_DEPRECATED;

#define __CCTOOLS_DEPRECATED __API_DEPRECATED("No longer supported", macos(10.0, 13.0), ios(1.0, 16.0), watchos(1.0, 8.0), tvos(1.0, 16.0))

@available(iOS, introduced: 1.0, deprecated: 16.0, message: "No longer supported")
public func getsegbyname(_ segname: UnsafePointer<CChar>!) -> UnsafePointer<segment_command_64>!

Is there a general reason why you should use another function instead of getsegbyname? Was using this function 'bad practice'?
It was a simple and practical search function to avoid having to go through the MachO structures manually in certain cases.

What's your use case for actually getting the section load command?

Mainly to read the LC_CODE_SIGNATURE data in the SEG_LINKEDIT segment at runtime.

But don't you have to parse the load commands anyway then, to get to the LC_CODE_SIGNATURE command?

I suggest that you add a short (if possible), self-contained example of your code that needs to be updated because of the deprecations.

@Siguza Yes, that's true. For me, getsegbyname was more of a convenience function that I could of course implement myself. My question is rather: is there something bad or 'dangerous' about getsegbyname that should not be used, and therefore has been marked as deprecated? I could not find an obvious reason for the deprecation. And then there's the question of whether there's a better alternative convenience function that does the same thing in a better way.

@ITGuy the only "danger" is that of Apple potentially removing it, or turning it into a stub that always returns NULL... but they might as well replace the segment struct and load command with a new one without notice.

@MartinR I understand your suggestion. But that would imho change the actual question, because I was concerned with what was fundamentally wrong with the use of getsegbyname that made it deprecated. Or what 'better'/new function has replaced it. Usually functions are marked as deprecated for a reason. I will amend my original question to avoid any misunderstanding.

@Siguza Thanks for your comments! The danger of Apple changing the MachO structures is of course always present, regardless of getsegbyname or the other functions marked as deprecated. So I take it from your answer that there is nothing fundamentally wrong or outdated about getsegbyname and that it needed to be replaced.

TL;DR: The replacement seems to be: getsectiondata

Here is the requisite snippet from getsect.h:
#ifndef __LP64__
/*
 * Runtime interfaces for 32-bit Mach-O programs.
 */
extern const struct section *getsectbyname(
    const char *segname,
    const char *sectname) __CCTOOLS_DEPRECATED_MSG("use getsectiondata(&__dso_handle,)");

extern uint8_t *getsectiondata(
    const struct mach_header *mhp,
    const char *segname,
    const char *sectname,
    unsigned long *size);

extern const struct segment_command *getsegbyname(
    const char *segname) __CCTOOLS_DEPRECATED;

extern uint8_t *getsegmentdata(
    const struct mach_header *mhp,
    const char *segname,
    unsigned long *size);

#else /* defined(__LP64__) */
/*
 * Runtime interfaces for 64-bit Mach-O programs.
 */
extern const struct section_64 *getsectbyname(
    const char *segname,
    const char *sectname);

extern uint8_t *getsectiondata(
    const struct mach_header_64 *mhp,
    const char *segname,
    const char *sectname,
    unsigned long *size);

extern const struct segment_command_64 *getsegbyname(
    const char *segname) __CCTOOLS_DEPRECATED;

extern uint8_t *getsegmentdata(
    const struct mach_header_64 *mhp,
    const char *segname,
    unsigned long *size);

#endif /* defined(__LP64__) */

Note that getsegbyname only has a generic deprecation message, but getsectbyname has use getsectiondata(&__dso_handle,)

From [V8] getsectdatafromheader_64 is deprecated in macOS 13.0 #45 it has:

Builds on macOS 13.0 will fail since getsectdatafromheader_64 is deprecated as of 13.0, replaced by getsectiondata().


So, it appears that getsectiondata is the replacement (for several functions) going forward. And, it exists (has existed) in both the 32 bit API and the 64 bit API.

UPDATE:

Note that the OP was asking for getsegbyname, not getsectbyname. Especially relevant since they seem to want the __LINKEDIT segment, which tends to not have any sections. –
Siguza

Good point. Upon further reflection, it seems that getsegmentdata would be the more suitable replacement for getsegbyname.
The main difference for the deprecated functions seems to be the lack of a struct mach_header * first argument. And, the newer functions return a uint8_t * pointer (i.e. caller has to cast this to the requisite struct pointer).
The older functions assumed a single file was being examined. The newer functions allow multiple files to be examined at the same time.
I haven't been able to find the definitive documentation for these functions. So, ultimately, one would have to try various ones to see which provides the same data.

UPDATE #2:

Close, but unfortunately no direct replacement for getsegbyname. getsegmentdata returns the data (payload) for a segment and not the segment_command command. As already mentioned, there no longer seems to be a direct equivalent. –
ITGuy

Stubbornly refusing to give up ...
Okay, no direct replacement. But, these are helper functions.
The file format is [somewhat] well known. And, although it can be extended, it can't easily be changed.
So, we can roll our own functions for whatever we need.
Here is the definition (32 bit) for getsegbyname:
const struct segment_command *
getsegbyname(
char *segname)
{
    struct segment_command *sgp;
    uint32_t i;
#ifndef RLD
#ifndef __OPENSTEP__
    struct mach_header *mhp = _NSGetMachExecuteHeader();
#else /* defined(__OPENSTEP__) */
    static struct mach_header *mhp = NULL;
        DECLARE_VAR(_mh_execute_header, struct mach_header);
        SETUP_VAR(_mh_execute_header);
    mhp = (struct mach_header *)(& USE_VAR(_mh_execute_header));
#endif /* __OPENSTEP__ */
#else /* defined(RLD) */
    mhp = (struct mach_header *)(&_mh_execute_header);
#endif /* defined(RLD) */

    sgp = (struct segment_command *)
          ((char *)mhp + sizeof(struct mach_header));
    for(i = 0; i < mhp->ncmds; i++){
        if(sgp->cmd == LC_SEGMENT)
        if(strncmp(sgp->segname, segname, sizeof(sgp->segname)) == 0)
            return(sgp);
        sgp = (struct segment_command *)((char *)sgp + sgp->cmdsize);
    }
    return(NULL);
}


Notice that (after the glop related to getting the mach_header pointer), the function is quite simple.

Note that one of issues [as mentioned above] is that the function uses a fixed/static mach_header buffer/pointer (hopefully, mmaped to the file). This ugly code is approximately 50% of the active lines of the function.

By providing the mach_header pointer as an argument, we can "improve" on the function. And, again, allow multiple files to be examined simultaneously.

Similar to ELF format (e.g. linux, posix, BSD), each subsection has a uint32_t cmdsize; field so it is also "extensible": we can skip over things we don't want/understand.


Here is a synthesized version (please pardon the gratuitous cleanup):
// increment pointer to struct as byte pointer
#define CPINC(_ptr,_inc) \
    ((char *) _ptr + _inc)

// get address of next entity in the file
#define NEXT(_ptr) \
    (__typeof__(_ptr)) CPINC(_ptr,_ptr->cmdsize)

const struct segment_command *
getsegbyname(const struct mach_header *mhp,const char *segname)
{
    struct segment_command *sgp;

    // point to first entity after the file header
    sgp = (struct segment_command *) CPINC(mhp,sizeof(*mhp));

    // loop through all entities
    for (uint32_t i = 0;  i < mhp->ncmds;  ++i, sgp = NEXT(sgp)) {
        // we only care about segment_command entities
        if (sgp->cmd != LC_SEGMENT)
            continue;

        // match the segment by name
        if (strncmp(sgp->segname, segname, sizeof(sgp->segname)) == 0)
            return sgp;
    }

    return NULL;
}

The cctools repo uses the Apple "Public" license, so we can [pretty much] make any changes we want. That includes shipping a modified, static version of the library. As well as some copy-and-paste with modifications as I've just done.

Note that the OP was asking for getsegbyname, not getsectbyname. Especially relevant since they seem to want the __LINKEDIT segment, which tends to not have any sections.

@Siguza You're absolutely right, in my case it's specifically about a segment without sections. @CraigEstey's answer still sums up some aspects quite well. Apple has probably mainly merged the 32 and 64 bit functions into common functions. And as part of this, they have simply marked the old functions as deprecated, even though they are theoretically still OK. However, it seems strange to me that there no longer seems to be a function to get a segment_command directly, sth. you could do with getsegbyname.

So the answer to my question seems to be: there is no direct replacement, you have to get the segment yourself in the future if you don't want to use the deprecated function?! I briefly considered accepting the answer anyway. Perhaps you would like to add this information to your answer @CraigEstey? Then I would close the question with your answer.

@ITGuy I've updated my answer. Have a look.

@Siguza I think you may be right. I've found another function and updated my answer.

@CraigEstey Close, but unfortunately no direct replacement for getsegbyname. getsegmentdata returns the data (payload) for a segment and not the segment_command command. As already mentioned, there no longer seems to be a direct equivalent.
